# add hidden input field to woocommerce checkout to pass data to payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a store running WooCommerce and the client needs us to pass a variable to the payment gateway (WorldPay) that is then included in an payment confirmation email sent form the gateway to the client.

WorldPay say i just need to add this to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="myValue" name="M_myName" />
```

After a lot of research I figured out how to create an array of the SKUs for each product in the cart. I have created a function that will grab each product SKU and add it to an array. Then outputs this array to replace "myValue" in the above.

My question is where do I need to put the < input >? I have added it to woocommerce > checkout > review-order.php, but this doesn't seem to work. It shows in the front-end but doesn't get passed the WorldPay.

Or would I need to add it to an existing action? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938974/woocommerce-form-field-and-hidden-fields) which seems to be talking about the similar issue – but then, where would I need to inject the output of that action, in which template?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The checkout form isn't submitted to WorldPay directly, so I doubt your extra field would be added automatically. You'd have to look into how the WorldPay gateway extension works and how their API works in general.

Comment: Just currently talking with the developer of the WorldPay plugin....

Comment: The plugin developer has nowupdated hiw plugin so that it can now pass these custom parameters over to WorldPay.