# Adding a hidden checkout field in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I want to include a link to a profile of the current user who submitted a checkout form through WooCommerce.

That is, to place automatically a current user’s author link like this in the hidden field: `example.com/author/username`

I want to achieve this by adding a hidden field in checkout form. So to get a link I would write something likes this:

```
<?php

$currentUser = get_current_user_id();

$user = get_user_by( 'id', $currentUser );

$userUrl = get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/author/' . $user->user_login;

echo $userUrl;
?>
```

My question is how can I create this type of hidden field in checkout form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_after_order_notes`** action hook, you can also directly output a hidden field with this user "author link" as a hidden value, that will be submitted at the same time with all checkout fields when customer will place the order.

Here is that code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_hidden_field', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_hidden_field( $checkout ) {

    // Get an instance of the current user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // The user link
    $user_link = home_url( '/author/' . $user->user_login );

    // Output the hidden link
    echo '<div id="user_link_hidden_checkout_field">
            <input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="user_link" id="user_link" value="' . $user_link . '">
    </div>';
}
```

Then you will need to save this hidden field in the order, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_checkout_hidden_field', 10, 1 );
function save_custom_checkout_hidden_field( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['user_link'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_user_link', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_link'] ) );

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and working

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you have any idea how to display this author link on order page and in the order email?

Comment: I figured how to place author link in the order emails if anyone needs it:  `add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['_user_link'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'User Link' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_user_link', true ),
    );
    return $fields;
}`

Comment: Question: why did you wrap the hidden input in a <div> ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file (or a plugin file,etc.)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'hidden_author_field' );

function hidden_author_field( $checkout ) {

$currentUser = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $currentUser );
$userUrl = get_bloginfo('home').'/author/'.$user->user_login;

    woocommerce_form_field( 'hidden_author', array(
        'type'          => 'hidden',
        'class'         => array('hidden form-row-wide'),
        ), $userUrl);

}
```

This code is untested, more reading here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ and here http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_form_field/. Please let me know if this worked for you and if not what the problem is.

Comment: some other issues arised :) trying to fix them first. will let you know

Comment: `'type' => 'hidden'` is not supported by `woocommerce_form_field`. Check: http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_form_field/ for function definition. You need to add custom code like what is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25622464/332188

Comment: @VivekAthalye Hidden fields are actually supported. Please check again.