# Is it possible to pass a special query parameter value to a WooCommerce product link?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am looking to use WooCommerce in a bit of a strange way, and I'm wondering if there is any way to make this possible. Here's my desired workflow:

**Step #1:** From a different site subdomain, provide a link to a certain virtual product, but with a query parameter with a unique user id number.

*Explanation:* The user is at `othersite.example.com`, and they get a link to buy a product in a WooCommerce store set up with a wordpress site at `https://example.com/product/virtual-product`

However, this product will be a payment to unlock something on the `othersite.example.com` site which has its own user and authentication system. (Firebase)

**Would it be possible to pass a user id from the `othersite.example.com` by way of a url query parameter and then have that included in the order info?**

ie. From the `othersite.example.com` someone could be given a link to the product like this `https://example.com/product/virtual-product?userid=00000000000000000`, with `00000000000000000` being their user id at `othersite.example.com`.

Then *if that `userid` query value could be included in the order*, the following steps should be doable.

**Step #2:** Have a webhook that fires when the product is purchased, telling a server managing the users for `othersite.example.com` that the user with `userid` `00000000000000000` has made a successful purchase of that product.

Is there a way to accept custom values like this to the order? Or is this totally out of the scope of WooCommerce's functionality?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I believe that it can be done by using a redirection/link directly to the checkout page, like: "**http://yourdomain.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=PRODUCTID&000000**" (tested)
- In the example, "checkout" stands for the name of your checkout page, "PRODUCTID" stands for the id of desired product, "000000" stands for the user id of redirected person in the other website.
- Then you can add a hidden input field to the checkout page (into checkout form, so you will see this value in order) and using the URL you can assign the "000000" (user id) to the value of this field.

I hope that works. If you have any problems with implementation, you can ask me.

*- Useful link for hidden input field addition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614905/11003615*

*- Useful link for getting value from current URL using JS: https://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/get-url-with-javascript/*

*- Useful link for getting value from current URL using PHP/Wordpress Core: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed*

*- Useful link (contains 4 parts) for adding a custom field to checkout & validating this field & saving this field to order fields & displaying the value of this field in order page: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-7*

Comment: Thanks so much, this really makes sense. But I can't get the hidden form value to show up in the order. I've added a input form like this `<input id="userid" type="hidden" name="userid" value="testusername">` but then when the order is created it's nowhere to seen. Do I need to do something for it to recognize and save this field? I get the order with all the details from a webhook, but that "userid" value is missing.

Comment: Hello again, did you assign the user id from the URL to this input field? If yes, can you test it using "console.log" or some other script to be sure that it gets the right data? If these are okay, then the problem is, as you said, to show this input in the order section in right way. To solve that, please check the link that I attached to my answer. Please let me know if you solve this.

Comment: I edited my answer by providing new links that you can get more help. I believe the last link will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I ended up using a totally different solution so I haven't tried and tested all this. The last link seems close to solving the answer. I guess you would have to create a hidden field with `'type'  => 'hidden'` and then on the template page add some client side javascript that takes the query parameter and adds it to the `value` of the hidden input.

Comment: Good to hear that. If you share your solution (not all your code but at least steps/guide of it), maybe other developers may use it :) Have a good day.

Comment: Ya the problem is that I never ended up making the solution. I decided to do the selling in a totally different way. Unfortunately WooCommerce was really slow with their webhook responses, and for my application case that really affected user flow. So I decided to create a totally separate payment system with Stripe.